# Unity. Объект экспортированный из blender поворачивается не корректно

Tags: unity3d, blender

На этой картинке видно что центр расположен не там где нужно

[image: Картинка 1]

Разместил пустой `GameObject` в том месте, относительно которого нужно вращение.

[image: Картинка 2]

Сделал сферу дочерним объектом `GameObject`, но точка почему то все равно не переместилась

[image: Картинка 3]

Подскажите пожалуйста, может я что-то не так делаю? Почему точка `GameObject` не присваивается сфере

Answer (score 0):

Я нашел такой ответ. В blender-е 3D курсор был установлен криво, я переставил его на центр сферы  все заработало